# Canvas image data is changed when sent to server

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, primefaces, xhtml

Following image will help in understanding this question.

[image]

The text in Notepad is at client side. And the text in the window titled "Value" is on server side.

If you note, in first line after "2WAAA" text is getting changed. Why is this happening ?

this following code is xhtml:
[image]

and this is javascript, using which we found out text in notepad
[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about your setup, but, in my eyes, those are simply two different png images. They start the same only because they have some png header data in common.

Comment: no they are same.
we are writing on canvas by mouse drag and drop, and it creates an image of all that writing...
then we are trying to send this image on server for storing in database, but this is happening ..

Comment: Are you resizing the canvas to the same size as the image? If not, then the image that the canvas is outputting with toDataURL is different than the input image. As the previous poster said, these look like two different images. So somewhere between the input and the output something is changing.